# Why does my SectionList sometimes only render one section?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript, react-native

I am having an issue with the `SectionList` component where sometimes it does not render all of the sections and instead it only renders the first section. I have done some debugging and may have found a fix, but I do not know why it fixes the issue.

My page will always render the first section, but sometimes it does not render the second section. Through some testing, I discovered that if I put all the items under one section, it will always render with no issues. This issue only seems to happen when there is another section that has a lot of items in it.

The code looks something like this:

```
const data = {
   sections: [{
      name: "First",
      items: [{
         name: "Item 1",
         ...   
      }]
   },
   {
      name: "Second",
      items: [{
         name: "Item 20",
         ...   
      }]
   }]
};

public render(): JSX.Element {
   return (
       <SafeAreaView>
           <ScrollView refreshControl={this.getRefreshControl()}>
               <SectionList
                   renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem(item)}
                   renderSectionHeader={(section) => this.renderHeader(section)}
                   sections={this.getSections(data)}
                   keyExtractor={(_, index) => String(index)}
               />
           </ScrollView>
       </SafeAreaView>
   );
}

getSections(data): SectionListData<any>[] {
    const sections = data.sections.map(section => {
        return {
            title: section.name,
            data: section.items
        };
    });

    return sections;
}
```

I did some testing and removed the `ScrollView` from the view hierarchy and it seemed to have fixed the issue and I haven't been able to reproduce it. I believe that the ScrollView is somehow causing issues with the SectionList sometimes, but I don't know why and I don't know how to prove it. Is there a way to dive deep and understand why this issue is happening? Or has anyone else encountered this issue before? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SectionLists have their own scrolling behavior provided by [VirtualizedList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist). If you wrap your SectionList in a ScrollView, the scroll event will be hijacked and it removes the sectioning behavior that you want.

Because SectionList lazy loads, if it doesn't have access to the scroll position then it can't calculate if it's beyond the onEndReachedThreshold and call onEndReached (to load more items).

SectionLists and FlatLists are designed to have infinite scroll, so you should never wrap them in another ScrollView. If instead you need to be able to scroll past your list of items on a screen (without lazy loading/pagination), I would load them all statically into a ScrollView.